# Rails - ActiveRecord: Compare Timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to show all posts where the timestamp *updated_at* is smaller than a certain date.

```
date = DateTime.parse("2014-12-14 09:38:00.000000")
@posts = Post.where("updated_at < #{date}")
```

This gives me a statement invalid error. Do I have to convert *updated_at* somehow? What else am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going with either (assuming your `date` is a valid `DateTime` object)

```
@posts = Post.where(["created_at < ?", date])
```

or

```
@posts = Post.where { updated_at < date }
```